# Three.js: Render an HTML page / DOM element onto the face of a cube?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am trying to adapt the example file canvas_geometry_cube.html provided with the Three.js package, and change each face of the cube to show an HTML page / DOM element (preferably DOM element). I look a look at ParticleDOMMaterial, but I have no idea how to use it or what it does. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: so where you able to find anything?

Comment: I was, I actually scrapped Three.js and used CSS transformations. It was good enough for my use case. If you want to know how to use that, check out the source of my personal site on my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMRenderer isn't a full 3d renderer, it's just able to apply z-indexes and scale, so a rotating cube through DOMRenderer is out of the question.

You could use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and apply it as a bitmap texture on the cube. I haven't really used html2canvas, but the demos are pretty impressive. Your mileage may vary.

Perhaps a better fit for your project would be CSS3 3D transforms. There is a library helps with this kind of problem called traqball, https://github.com/dirkweber/traqball.js.

You can view a demo here: http://www.eleqtriq.com/wp-content/static/demos/2010/rotation/index.html

Comment: If possible, I'm looking for a way to render the actual HTML on the cube, not bitmap textures (i.e. buttons and links still work like a normal html page). Can traqball help with this? I've seen a three.js demo with google maps rendered on a cube interactively, can I do this with an html page?

Comment: I guess you mean this: http://www.playmapscube.com/, that's not the actual html google maps but an adaptation of their webgl version. With CSS transforms you can still interact with the content, here is an adapted version of a cube I found http://cssdeck.com/labs/7ihk9ib6/5 try writing on the text fields.

Comment: Ah yes, thats exactly what I'm looking for! So does traqball work independently from three.js, or do I use them together? Also, does the rendering always make the elements look a bit blurry like that cube demo you linked?

Comment: The demo I linked doesn't use traqball, it's just CSS animations with CSS transforms. If you click on the "x" icon you can see the code. Traqball is for controlling the cube with the mouse. You can disregard it if you just need to animate the cube. You should probably start with this tutorial to understand what's going on. http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html

Answer (score 4):

*To update this old question from some recent improvemetns in Three.js and for future readers*

**Three.js actually supports CSS3D** as a render output now and therefore you can manipulate a HTML page / DOM elements using CSS 3D transforms.

For an example, see here: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/css3d_periodictable.html

Comment: I'm just catching up on this thread now (2 years later) Is there an include for Three.js that does this more easily now?  With a fully interactive webpage inside a THREE.Plane ?