# Aframe.io integration with FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, aframe

Hello I am working on small project based on Mozilla Hub and I would like to ask you. How to integrate
FullCalendar with Aframe.io.
I added FullCalendar to my project and It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw7ey.png)

I would like to render it in 3d and show like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDXkr.png) but don't change design of FullCalendar.

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';


 export function calendar() {
  const nel =  document.createElement("a-entity")
  nel.setAttribute("id", "calendarEl") 
  nel.setAttribute("class", "Calendar-container") 
  nel.setAttribute("position", "0 0 0")
  nel.object3D.visible = true
  let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ],
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    height: '500px',

  });
  calendar.render();
  document.querySelector("a-scene").appendChild(nel);
};
```

I tried to search something about integration calendar to aframe. If you have any idea how to do it correctly. I will be pleased

Comment: I don't know anything about aframe (only fullCalendar)...is it normally able to re-render standard HTML components in 3D automatically? I mean would you have expected it to automatically convert things into the 3D format you showed in your second picture? It's unclear if you think there is a bug in a standard process somewhere, or you're asking us to code a 3D version of the calendar for you from scratch.

Comment: `threejs` has a `CSS3D` renderer, but with `a-frame` I'd try rendering the calendar on a plane ([like in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337281/2425787)).